# New line character not included in [:space:] group

Tags: grep, locale

When executing search via grep using [:space:] group new line characters are not detected as belonging to the group. Any ideas why is that and how to include new line character in the [:space:] group (tab and space are properly recognized)? Any chance this is because of empty LC_CTYPE variable when echoed in terminal? (when using locale command it is set to LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8")

Grep version: 2.25
System: Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot
Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grep searches each line separately. It doesn't matter what you do in your regex; the string being searched doesn't contain `\n` anyway.

Comment: ‘[:space:]’
Space characters: in the ‘C’ locale, this is tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space. See Usage, for more discussion of matching newlines.
this is from grep manual.
I mean grepping with 'a[[:space:]]' should find both line 'a\t' and 'a\n' lines, shouldn't it ?

Comment: @koko There are no `a\n` lines. `\n` is what terminates each line, so if you have a 3 line file like `a\t\na\nxyz\n`, grep searches `a\t`, `a`, and `xyz` separately.

Comment: but adding explicitly '$' character works and using extended notation a([[:space:]]|$) catches both mentioned lines. this is desired behavior?

Comment: @koko `$` matches the end of the string. Since grep matches each line separately, `$` indeed matches at the end of each line.

Comment: ok, thank you for your explanation. what is the best way to catch occurances of letter "a" followed by a whitespace or end of line in a file? do you have to use extended regexp? I tried "a[$[:space:]]" but it didn't work

Comment: @koko `[$...]` doesn't work because `[` `]` is a character class; it matches exactly one character. But you're not trying to match a literal `$` sign, you're trying to match end-of-line, which isn't a character. `a([[:space:]]|$)` (or `a\([[:space:]]\|$\)` in "basic" syntax) is the best you can do in POSIX regex. In Perl regex you could also use `a(?!\S)`.

Comment: @melpomene POSIX BRE has no alternation, the `\|` syntax is a GNU extension. I'd say in POSIX BRE, it'd have to be `-e 'a[[:space:]]' -e 'a$'`.